# Passing an XSLT variable in between <text> tag(i.e.opening and closing <text> tag) in SVG in an XSLT program

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I've spent a couple of days trying to figure out how to solve this problem which I'm about to share with you all. Your help will be truly appreciated.

So, there's this XML code that calls the following XSLT code snippet which I'm working on.

```
<xsl:for-each select="roomname">
                        <xsl:variable name="rmnmstX" select="@startx" />
                        <xsl:variable name="rmnmstY" select="@starty" />
                        <xsl:variable name="rmnmenX" select="@endx" />
                        <xsl:variable name="rmnmenY" select="@endy" />
                        <xsl:variable name="rmnmname" select="@name" />


                            <text x="{$rmnmstX*$ts}" y="{$rmnmstY*$ts}" style="font-family: Verdana;
           font-size  : 5;
           stroke     : #0000ff;
           fill       : #0000ff;
           opacity    : 0.65">DC ROOM</text>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Here, in between the SVG **text** tag where I've included the text **DC ROOM** I wish to pass the value of the last variable **rmnmname** in place of **DC ROOM**. I tried doing this by writing **{$rmnmname}** in place of **DC ROOM** but when I tested the XML document which calls this XSLT code I see **{$rmnmname}** instead of the value of the **name** attribute that I've passed in the XML code. The section of the XML code I'm manipulating to test the output looks like this:

```
<roomname endx="5" endy="3" id="RM0002" startx="2" starty="2" name="DC ROOM 1"></roomname>
```

I hope I'm able to get this through to you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of) to output value of your XSL variable as a text node :

```
.....
0.65"><xsl:value-of select="$rmnmname"/></text>
.....
```

Or just get the value from the source XML variable if you don't plan to use the same value anywhere else :

```
.....
0.65"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></text>
.....
```

Comment: Bro you just made my day. Thanks a ton!